# Cache Busting with Query Strings

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching

I would like to know the best process for cache busting using query strings, I've read up on a few different sources but I still don't quite understand how to implement it..

If I reference a new file in my HTML header, e.g. "style.css?v=1.1", does that file  have to be renamed to reflect the new appendage?

Or should I just leave the filename as "style.css" and let the server figure it out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Increasing version (`style.css?v=1`) of files is good approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer got deleted by mods even though it was legitimate...

> You only need to add the iterative appendage to your code and there is
>   no need to alter the actual file name.